# How to get only the text of a json object when saved into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using the following to retrieve results form google which works fine:

```
function myGoogle() {
  var termS;          
  termS = $("#usp-title").val();
  var myKey = 'MY_KE';
  $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1", {
    q: termS,
    alt: "json",
    cx: "MY_CX",
    key: myKey,
    num: 10,
    hl: "it",
    siteSearch: "https://it.wikipedia.org/",
    language: "it",
    filter: "1",
    safe: "high"
  },
  function (data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
      var uniq = uniqueId('thing_');
      var $items = $($('<h3>"' + item.title + '"</h3>'));
      console.log($items);
    });
  });
}
```

The console outputs all the objects while instead i would like to only see the actual title text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
$items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.title);
});
```

* I am assuming that you are getting data similar to this
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#response

"items" is an array, thus you can iterate through the array via [`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: yes sorry, forgot to give my own answer, that is correct, i found it later on.